# Proper actions and covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying this exercise from Hatcher's book:

"23. Show that if a group $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on a Hausdorff space $X$, then the action is a covering space action. (Here 'properly discontinuously' means that each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\{g \in G \mid U \cap g(U) \neq \varnothing\}$ is finite.) In particular, a free action of a finite group on a Hausdorff space is a covering space action."

Partial solution:

Suppose that $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on a Hausdorff space $X$. Choose an element $x \in X$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that the set $S=\{g \in G \mid U \cap g(U) \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite. For each $g \in S$, choose an open set $V_g$ containing $g x$ such that the sets $\left\{V_g \mid g \in S\right\}$ are pairwise disjoint. Let
$$
V=\bigcap_{g \in S} g^{-1}\left(V_g\right)
$$
Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that satisfies:

"Each $y \in Y$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that all the images $g(U)$ for varying $g \in G$ are disjoint. In other words, $g_1(U) \cap g_2(U) \neq \varnothing$ implies $g_1=g_2$."

I stuck here. Why $V$ satisfies that condition?